# How to do grouping by a date span?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

Conside this Table Structure.

```
 Key       ID       VISITDATE
 1         1        2011-01-07
 2         1        2011-01-09
 3         2        2011-01-10
 4         1        2011-01-12
 5         3        2011-01-12
 6         1        2011-01-15
 7         2        2011-01-21
 9         1        2011-02-28
 10        2        2011-03-21
 11        1        2011-01-06
```

I need to get all the IDs,Key,min(VisitDate) where VisitDate is within 10 days span?if you have two visits within 10 days one row need to be there in the result.

**Result**

```
 KEY      ID        VISITDATE
 11        1         2011-01-06
 3         2         2011-01-10
 5         3         2011-01-12
 7         2         2011-01-21
 9         1         2011-02-28
10         2         2011-03-21
```

Can this be done without a self join. i have a query which does a self join with the table on ID and check the datediff.is there a better solution?can we use  recursive CTE here?

**EDIT**

Prefer a solution which can use the index on date column

Comment: What if you have a visit, wait 8 days, visit again, wait 8 days, visit again? There should be two groups, right? But which two rows? There are two ways to perform the grouping (AB)C or A(BC), and you haven't specified which you want. Or am I missing something?

Comment: How is each 10 days span defined? Starting on the first visit?

Comment: @Mike yeah. starting on first visit...

Comment: @Mark . yes two groups. i need the row corresponds to  min (Visitdate) .starts with the initial (AB)C

Comment: OK so what if someone visits on day 1, day 18, day 24? Is that 2 groups or 3?

Comment: 2 groups...day 1 - group 1, day 18,day 24 - group 2

Answer (score 2):

Yes a CTE would work nicely for this (everything with me is CTEs lately)...

```
;WITH TenDayVisits
AS (

SELECT 
        ID
        ,MIN(VisitDate) AS VisitDate
    FROM Visits
    GROUP BY ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.ID
        ,v.VisitDate
    FROM Visits AS v
    JOIN TenDayVisits AS t ON v.ID = t.ID               
        AND DATEDIFF(dd,t.Visitdate,v.VisitDate) > 10
)

SELECT
    DISTINCT  
    v.[key]
    ,t.id
    ,t.VisitDate
FROM TenDayVisits as T
JOIN Visits AS v ON t.id = v.id
    AND t.VisitDate = v.VisitDate
```

Comment: Thanks. I threw the DISTINCT in because I was getting some duplicates back...you might be able to tweak the recursive part of the CTE to get rid of the dupes but the DISTINCT works just as well.

Comment: is there a way to remove the keylookups(in execution plan) for performance reasons..ie modifying the query so that it could use index on date

Comment: That's difficult to answer without knowing what indexes you have. If you have a clustered index on [Key] you'd probably want to pull that into the CTE for joining it back to Visits instead of the id and the date but that might get tricky in keeping the CTE returning the right values. There's also a bug regarding `DATEDIFF` and indexes: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/630583/incorrect-estimate-with-condition-that-includes-datediff

Comment: sorry .it seems like there is a problem with this.when you have a visitdate which is less than the previous ones for the same id in the table coming with a higher key.